# Access Django admin from Firebase

Tags: django, firebase, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-run

I have a website which has a React frontend hosted on Firebase and a Django backend which is hosted on Google Cloud Run. I have a Firebase rewrite rule which points all my API calls to the Cloud Run instance. However, I am unable to use the Django admin panel from my custom domain which points to Firebase.

I have tried two different versions of rewrite rules -

```
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "/**",
          "run": {
            "serviceId": "serviceId",
            "region": "europe-west1"
          }
        },
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
```

---  AND ---

```
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "/api/**",
          "run": {
            "serviceId": "serviceId",
            "region": "europe-west1"
          }
        },
        {
          "source": "/admin/**",
          "run": {
            "serviceId": "serviceId",
            "region": "europe-west1"
          }
        },
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
```

I am able to see the log in page when I go to `url.com/admin/`, however I am unable to go any further. It just refreshes the page with empty email/password fields and no error message. Just as an FYI, it is not to do with my username and password as I have tested the admin panel and it works fine when accessing it directly using the Cloud Run url.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't actually find an answer to why the admin login page was just refreshing when I was trying to log in using the Firebase rewrite rule, however I thought of an alternative way to access the admin panel using my custom domain.

I have added a custom domain to the Cloud Run instance so that is uses a subdomain of my site domain and I can access the admin panel by using `admin.customUrl.com` rather than `customUrl.com/admin/`.