# Login not working in django when using rewrites from firebase hosting to cloud run

Tags: django, containers, gunicorn, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-run

**Current Setup:** I've got a Django application behind gunicorn running on Cloud Run. Since the region it is deployed in does not support Custom Domains, I have a firebase hosting setup with the following code:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "/**",
      "run": {
        "serviceId": "website",
        "region": "ap-south1"
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

The relevant settings in settings.py:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['.<domain>.com']
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

**The problem:** However, the login form on /admin does not work if I access the site using my domain name https://doman.com/admin even though it works fine if I use the Cloud Run endpoint https://endpoint-uw.a.run.app.

**Faulty behaviour:** When accessing it from my domain, the login page shows up, I enter my credentials and log in, it adds the relevant cookies to my browser but then it redirects me back to the login page.

Could it be that since the URL is being rewritten by firebase django is expecting a cookie from `uw.a.run.app`? I tried adding the setting `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.<domain>.com'` but that did not fix it either, it just made the Cloud Run endpoint stop working as well.

Any advice on how to fix this or how to diagnose what is going wrong would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try adding a custom domain to the Cloud Run instance so that it uses a subdomain of your site domain and you can access the admin panel by using `admin.customUrl.com` rather than `customUrl.com/admin/`. Refer to this thread [1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65470975/access-django-admin-from-firebase

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue. Am having the same problem

Answer (score 2):

The relevant settings in settings.py:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = "__session"
```

as firebase send cookie in the name "__session"

Comment: This worked for me, thanks